# Print to a network printer in C#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am attempting to print to a network servia via C# in VS2010 but have run into difficulties getting it to work.  If I use the "print" Verb insted it prints fine but only to the default printer.  I am using the PrintTo Verb to try and specify a printer.  In my case using print verb I successfully can print to the same network printer that I am trying to print to using the printto verb after I change my default printer to a different printer.  Here is the code I am currently using.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    private string FindPrinter(string printerName)
    {
        string query = string.Format("SELECT * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name LIKE '%{0}'", printerName);
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        ManagementObjectCollection printers = searcher.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject printer in printers)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(printer.Properties["PortName"].Value.ToString()))
            {
                return printerName = string.Format(@"\\{0}\{1}", printer.Properties["PortName"].Value.ToString(), printerName);
            }
        }

        return printerName;
    }

    private void Print(string fileName, string printerName)
    {
        PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
        ps.PrinterName = printerName;
        if (ps.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName);
                using (PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog())
                {
                    pd.ShowDialog();

                    printerName = this.FindPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName);
                    if (printerName.IndexOf(@"\\") == 0)
                    {

                        processStartInfo.Verb = "PrintTo";
                        processStartInfo.Arguments = printerName;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        processStartInfo.Verb = "print";
                    }
                }

                processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                Process printProcess = new Process();
                printProcess.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
                bool printStarted = printProcess.Start();
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} printed to {1}", fileName, printerName), "Report Print", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Report Print", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} printer does not exist.  Please contact technical support.", printerName), "Report Print", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

only use verb PrintTo and
use the double quotes to quote the printerName

```
processStartInfo.Verb = "PrintTo";
processStartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + printerName + "\"";
```